# AngularJS ngClass expression and array combination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I currently have the following expression in `ng-class`, in the view of an AngularUI Bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal-body mdl-body"
     ng-class="{ 'is-msg': vm.message.type == 'msg',
                 'height-limit': vm.message.hasHeight }">
```

But I also want to pass an array of custom classes, like this:

```
ng-class="vm.message.classes"
```

This is where the modal is called in controller:

```
modalService.open({
  type: "okay",
  title: "Terms & Conditions",
  content: $scope.APISettingData.signup_term_and_condition,
  classes: ["h-md", "text-info"],
  isHtml: true,
  hasHeight: true
});
```

Both ways works without each other but they didn't work when I tried to combine them.

Is it possible to do this? Please advise me some ideas and solutions.

Comment: an idea that you could try, is to create another container, inside or outside... not the best solution though

Comment: `ng-class` is rather simple directive, you can always make your own, that does exactly what you want. Accepts arrays or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another syntax that looks like this

```
<div ng-class="[custom1, custom2, {'text-danger': isBadJuJu()}]">Some Text</div>
```

Where `custom1` and `custom2` are variables within the scope of your controller, and the `{}` is a set of expressions, much like the syntax you are using in your first example

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have the ng-class assigned to a variable in the `scope`. i.e `ng-class = customClasses`

and in the `controller` something like this. Doing this makes you have a complete control on what classes must be applied on the modal.

**EDIT:**
Check this sample application in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F4J2L80YpdEr99PN745O?p=preview)

```
$scope.customClasses = {
   'is-msg': $scope.message.type == 'msg',
   'height-limit': $scope.message.hasHeight,
   "h-md" : true, 
   "text-info": true
};
```

Comment: We still have to pre-define the classes, I would like to pass any class I want.

Comment: `I would like to pass any class I want` what does this actually mean ?

Comment: Misunderstood, I see what you mean, but I sitll need to use the expressions, they are needed in other parts of the application.

Comment: @Nhan Please accept the answer if it solved your case. It can help others too :)